# Laravel print error if bad query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm laravel newbie, I have written a simple code:

```
Route::get('users/{uname}/{uid}', function($uname, $uid)
{
    $u = DB::table('users')->where('login', $uname)->first();

    return View::make('users', 
        array(
            'username'  => $u->login,
            'userid'    => $u->uid
        )
    );
});
```

I have 2 questions regarding this code,

**First:** Is this code valid?

**Second:** How can I show 404 error when query is not found? For example if I write site.com/users/badusername/badid then show 404 error, not blank page.

Thanks in advance !

P.S how can i make $u query to two wheres? For example WHERE login = ? AND uid = ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:** code looks ok. You could also make use of a little un-documented feature of dynamic where methods, and call it like that:

```
DB::table('users')->whereLogin($uname)->first();
```

**Second:** In order to throw 404 error, you can simply call

```
App::abort(404);
```

**Third:** You can chain the **where()** methods, e.g.:

```
$u = DB::table('users')->where('login', $uname)->where('uid', $uid)->first();
```

The query above doesn't make much sense though, as **uid** and probably **username** as well are unique and fetching just by one of them should be enough. If you have a Eloquent model for your users, you could also use model's **find()** or **findOrFail()** methods to search by primary key. Especially **findOrFail()** is very useful, as it throws 404 exception if model cannot be found, so no need to wrap it in the **if** statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're code is valid, but you can simplified it.

```
get('users/{uname}/{uid}', function($uname, $uid)
{
    $user = User::where('login', $uname)->where('uid', $uid)->first();

    if (! $user) abort(404);

    return view('users', compact('user'));
});
```

To use this code you need to use Laravel 5+ and to have a model for your User table.

Also, as you can see, I have write another condition to handle the `uid`.

**Note that I send `$user` to the view.**

Comment: It won't throw an exception. It will return null if a matching model is not found. Only eloquent findOrFail() throws exceptions

Comment: Correct! Laravel 4 automatism... Thanks, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you have User model.
Try:

```
Route::get('users/{uname}/{uid}', function($uname, $uid)
{
    $u = User::where('login', $uname)->where('uid',$uid)->first();

    if(!$u->isEmpty()) {
          return View::make('users',array('username'  => $u->login,
                                          'userid'    => $u->uid));
    }else{
         App::abort(404);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're using Eloquent the best way is to use `findOrFail`. In this case `firstOrFail` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I know but I use it intentionaly not to mess with caching an exception  - to make code cleaner and simplier as OP said he is newbie

Comment: Well your way is not simple neither is it cleaner.  I was just improving your answer with better ways. Also the OP didn't mention using Eloquent you're making an assumption so you're still likely to be wrong.